# Can I share workspace in eclipse in dualbooting system?

Tags: dual-boot, eclipse, workspaces

I am dualbooting Windows 8 and Ubuntu (each os has it's own partition, third partition is shared). Can I use a same workspace for Windows and Ubuntu version of eclipse? I am not doing any serious development, I'm just learning java atm, so it is not problem for me if some files get corrupted. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the partition is NTFS you can share the workspace. Linux partition are difficult to load in Windows.

Just set the workspace to a directory off the root of the NTFS root drive so in Windows it will be c:\workspace and when you boot into Ubuntu and click on the Windows Partition via Nautilus it will have that directory in /media/username/drivename/workspace or whatever Nautilus decides to call the drivename

Comment: Thank you! That partition is NTFS, I hope i wont have any problems. :D